# write reverse in scala, using foldleft

Tags: list, scala, foldleft

here's an implementation:

```
def reverse[A](l: List[A]): List[A] = foldLeft(l, List[A]())((acc,h) => Cons(h,acc))
```

I don't understand what is inderstood by the compiler with (acc,h); initially, the f function meets (ListA,l), which are 2 lists, so is Cons working with 2 lists also?

thanks

Comment: curious, where did you find this implementation? Was this in the FP in Scala book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cons` works with one list and one element, just as the function passed to `foldLeft` does.

The declaration of `foldLeft` on `List[A]` is:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

So we can write your impl as:

```
l.foldLeft(List[A]())((acc, h) => ...)
```

and we can see that the type `B` is `List[A]`, so the two arguments to our `f` are `acc` (of type `List[A]`) and `h` (of type `A`).